# Remove suffix from string by regular expression in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've a string that ends with an even number of `0`'s padded to it. I want to remove these `0`'s by a regular expression `(00)*`:

```
ababababab000000 => ababababab
abababab00       => abababab
abab000000000    => abab0
aba00000         => aba0
```

How can this be done in Bash? In general, how would I remove any suffix using a regex?

Comment: What efforts did you make? We can help you out, if you make some attempts to start with

Comment: See also [Unix.SE: How to detect end of line with sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206922/how-to-detect-end-of-line-with-sed).

Answer (score 2):

Use `sed -r` to search and replace arbitrary regexes with `s/regex/replacement/`. `$` anchors the regex to the end of each line.

```
$ sed -r 's/(00)*$//' <<< 'ababababab000000'
ababababab
$ sed -r 's/(00)*$//' <<< 'abababab00'
abababab
$ sed -r 's/(00)*$//' <<< 'abab000000000'
abab0
$ sed -r 's/(00)*$//' <<< 'aba00000'
aba0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo ababababab000000 abababab00 abab000000000 aba00000 | sed 's/00//g'
ababababab abababab abab0 aba0
```

Comment: what if a string is `a00b00000`

Comment: @Kent - Good point.

Comment: the final $ is missing, which is why @John-Kugelman got the votes